# MediaRecorder for Recording Screen with output format Mpeg2_TS Media Server died error

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

For screen capturing I followed the below link

https://www.truiton.com/2015/05/capture-record-android-screen-using-mediaprojection-apis/

I changed the output format to MPEG_2_TS. On starting the recording it gives the following error.

`W/IMediaDeathNotifier: media server died`

Below is how my mediaRecorder object looks like.

```
private void initRecorder() {
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_2_TS);

            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputFileName());
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(48000);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30); // 30
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(128000);
            WindowManager window = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            int rotation = window.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation + 90);
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            mVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
            mMediaRecorder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private VirtualDisplay createVirtualDisplay() {

        return mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("MainActivity", DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, mScreenDensity,
                DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, mMediaRecorder.getSurface(), null, null);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!!